# Finding dissertations as reference material

Tags: thesis, mathematics, computer-science, literature-search

I'm a mathematician/computer scientist (my interests lie around the intersection of the two), and often when I want an introduction to a new research area I find that well-written dissertations are the best way to get up-to-speed quickly.

The problem is that I have no good way of finding these resources. I just Google "[subject name] dissertation" and look through the topics, or if I'm lucky someone in the field that I know will point me to a specific person's thesis. Is there any better resource for finding recent dissertations that are publicly available?

Comment: Find good paper on the topic from a year or two ago, from a university. Google that university's library listings of theses, and search on several of the initial names on the paper...

Comment: I'm assuming you know of the arXiv, you could try "[subject name] arxiv review/thesis"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only comprehensive international compendium of theses and dissertations that I know of is [ProQuest Dissertations & Theses Global](https://www.proquest.com/pqdtglobal). I think it is especially good in covering the United States and Canada, but I cannot personally vouch for its comprehensiveness in dissertations from other countries.

Other than that, most collections seem to be on a national level (e.g., [HAL for France](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/)).

Comment: ProQuest is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

It is good to see which university is a powerhouse of your field and search for something like "University of XXX thesis repository". For example Eindhoven University is very good in photonics and they have a repository [that looks like that](https://research.tue.nl/en/studentTheses/)

For most of the European universities there's [DART initiative](https://www.dart-europe.org/basic-search.php) that offers a wide search.